# Can I change the width of the Facebook "Like" button's comment box?

Tags: javascript, html, css, facebook, facebook-like

The [Facebook "Like" button](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) allows you to set a width for the button itself and its related content (e.g., number of likes). However, I don't see any options in the documentation to control the width of the comment box that appears after you click the "Like" button:

https://skitch.com/troywarr/8d761/like-button-facebook-developers

Am I missing an option for that, or is there no way to do it? I can override the width of the `<iframe>` that contains the comment box using CSS, but that doesn't change the width of the `<iframe>`'s contents, so they overflow and are clipped. I also can't change any styling within the comment box since it's hosted in a different domain.

---

**UPDATE:**

Not sure why this question was downrated - please comment if there's an issue with what I'm asking.

The content of the comment box is most definitely not accessible via JavaScript or CSS. It's created in an `<iframe>`, which rules out CSS styling from the parent document, and it's hosted on Facebook's domain, which prohibits cross-domain scripting:

https://skitch.com/troywarr/8d6wj/facebook-like-button

All I'm asking is:

- Am I missing a setting (documented or not) that allows me to choose the width of this comment box?
- If there is no setting, is there a clever way to set the width of the comment box that's better than setting the width of its `<iframe>` via CSS?

Answer (score 1):

You can change anything you want if it is your site!

Use CSS and enforce the rule by using !important directive

Inline CSS takes the highest precedence, then embedded than global ... etc!

Hope this helps.

Edit: You can target iframe out outside via CSS. Example is below

```
#container iframe  /* iframe is inside a element with ID="container"
{
width:200px !important;
}
```

The above will override all width if they were not not specified with !important tag

Comment: You can target iframe from outside even if you can't write inline css. Having it hosted by facebook, will get you somewhat limited though. Updated my answer.

Comment: Note that you can't actually style the document contained within the iframe, just the iframe element itself. I had tried to just set the iframe width using CSS, hoping that the content box's content would reflow accordingly, but that's not the case. Narrowing the iframe just clips its content (the comment box), which isn't acceptable per my project's requirements.